# Price comparison restful api

Tags: python, algorithm, web-crawler, scrapy, flask-restful

I’m trying to build a restful api that would compare prices from specific websites. 
I started with scrapping product names, prices, and product image url and saved it to a csv file. At this point I have website’s A products and products of website B. 
However, there was no way of knowing that a specific product is the same in both files to actually compare the prices. My approach was to use a string matching library called fuzzywuzzy which works fine. 
I feel like this wouldn’t be practical in this case because prices change continually and products might get removed.

What would be a better solution in solving this problem?

Comment: What is your actual question?  You said fuzzywuzzy works fine, so what are you having trouble with?

Comment: @JohnGordon It works fine, but I would have to run the scrapper every couple of days to keep the data up to date. What I want is a way to automatically get updates maybe by using spiders which I’m not really familiar with and not sure if they would work also.

Comment: I don't see any way to automatically get updates, unless the sites provide one.  I think you'll just have to scrape every few days.  You can start by just doing a HEAD request on each product, and if the last modified date hasn't changed since the last time, you wouldn't have to scrape that product again.

Comment: In most cases questions like "Provide a (better) solution for…" are considered too broad for SO. On the other hand specific questions about specific programming problems are very welcome.